# How to render the page after fetching the data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following function to check the users

```
export const authCheckState = () => {
  return dispatch => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    const email = localStorage.getItem("email");
    if (token === undefined) {
      dispatch(logout());
    } else {
      const expirationDate = new Date(localStorage.getItem("expirationDate"));
      if (expirationDate <= new Date()) {
        dispatch(logout());
      } else {
        dispatch(authSuccess(email, token));
        dispatch(
          checkAuthTimeout(
            (expirationDate.getTime() - new Date().getTime()) / 1000
          )
        );
      }
    }
  };
};
```

And for that i did the special initialization function that will take all the needed functions and dispatch them

```
initialState = {
    initialized: false
};

const appReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case INITIALIZED_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                initialized: true
            }

        default:
            return state;
    }
}


export const initializedSuccess = () => ({type: INITIALIZED_SUCCESS});

export const initializeApp = () => (dispatch) => {
    let promise = dispatch(authCheckState());

    Promise.all([promise])
    .then(() => {
        dispatch(initializedSuccess());
    });
}
```

And after that i am putting initialization function to the App's componentDidMount function

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.initializeApp();
  }
```

and after i am doing that

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  initialized: state.app.initialized
})
```

but after that i am still getting the data too late and i have to refresh the page to see the data. How to implement this feature?

Answer (score 0):

You should fetch data in the component itself. Use Redux for storing the data so that you can use it later or manipulate it. (If you need to do so!)

This how the process should be,

1. Make an API request on componentDidMount.
2. Store the data in redux.
3. Use that data in the component coming in the form of props using Redux.

Comment: But i am doing that in the App's componentDidMount(), is it any difference between App's componentDidMount() and Component'
s componentDidMount()?